# Cannot find symbol error?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

The compiler says that it cannot find Getdata on the code. Not sure why?

The exact error is:

```
Inventory.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
            int i = GetData.getInt(menu);
                    ^
symbol:   variable GetData
location: class Inventory
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

class Inventory
{
  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
    Database db = new Database();
    Database dpl = new Database();

    String menu = "1. Add product\n2. Sell product\n3. Delete product\n4. Modify  product\n5. Display information\n6. Exit";
    boolean more = true;

    while(more)
    {
        int i = GetData.getInt(menu);
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                   // Creating an order and additing this order to the database
                   IO.display("Add new product", "New product", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    String street = GetData.getWord("Enter street address");
                    String city = GetData.getWord("Enter city");
                    String state = GetData.getWord("Enter state");
                    String zip = GetData.getWord("Enter zip code");
                    Address addr = new Address(street, city, state, zip);

                    String company_name =  GetData.getWord("Enter name of the company");
                    Manufacturer m = new Manufacturer(addr, company_name);

                    String product_name =  GetData.getWord("Enter name of product");
                    String product_code =  GetData.getWord("Enter product code: xx-xxx-xxxx");
                    double price = GetData.getInt("Enter unit price");

                    Product p = new Product(m,  product_name,  product_code, price);

                     int quantity =  GetData.getInt("Enter quantity");

                     Order ord = new Order(p, quantity);

                    db.add(ord);
            break;
            case 2:

            break;
            case 6:
                    more = false;
            break;

            default:
            break;
          } // End switch
      } // End while
  } // End main

    static void display(String s, String ss, int m){}
} // End inventory
```

Comment: What is your GetData? Does it have a getInt method?

Comment: Where did you define your `GetData` class?

Comment: paste ur GetData class

Comment: What GetData? that was not given to us. I thought it was a function of Java like math.

Comment: It is not. It is a a separate class file.

Comment: I just realized my professor just is an ass, and this is an example, not the program to finish, So I'm screwed, I'll close this question, thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the class GetData with all it's methods first to use it.